# Autoplay and Playlist not working on multiple youtube API iframe players

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Problem do not appear on chrome /!\

I'm using the iframe player providing by the youtube API. I've created two players and hide one of them if a button isn't pressed or held.
Furthermore I use a playlist for each of them and the option autoplay off playerVars is enable.

My problem is, when the second video in the playlist comes to the player2 it is not loading automatically and the video isn't the next one in the playlist wished.

An example is running at this address -> http://dev.alphas-projects.com
Wait ~1 min so that the second video appears and press or hold spacebar to switch to the second player. You will see the issue.

NB: I'm pretty sure that the problem resides to the youtube player API code because if we disable the 'display: none' of the second video player the issue appears.

Here is my code.

```
 <div id=medias>
  <div id=media-1 class=video-background>
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <div id="player1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id=media-2 class=video-background style="display: none">
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <div id="player2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player1;
var player2;


function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
        videoId: 'Ja53GAN1lpA',
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'loop': 1,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'controls': 0,
            'rel': 0,
            'playlist': 'WCBDPLga_tI,8RYpwS1vxKk'
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady1
        }
    })
    player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
        videoId: 'B7C1eiP8qVU',
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'loop': 1,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'controls': 0,
            'rel': 0,
            'playlist': 'ou0E2tJrU_Q,yD1eVgZrD6U'
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady2
        }
    })
}

function onPlayerReady1(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    player1.setVolume(30);
}

function onPlayerReady2(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    player2.setVolume(30);
    player2.mute();
}
```

Comment: I used your code above ( but removed the style="display: none"). It seems to work fine. So your js in your page might be to blame. Also, videoID "yD1eVgZrD6U" is blocked and not viewable.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD1eVgZrD6U Works for me... Did you wait the second video in the playlist bc the first one is showing properly. It only happens when the second comes. Anyway, I will try to test the code with a clean project to see if my js is the real problem.

Comment: yD1eVgZrD6U is blocked from playing outside of YouTube. Test it on a stand alone embedded player to see.

Comment: Yep it was just an option I unchecked yesterday on youtube

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found your problem.
First switch your `id="media-2"` div with your `id="media-1"`. This is just for practicality.  Then remove the `style="display: none;"` from your `id="media-2"` div.

Then in the player code when "state" is equal to "playing", set

```
        $('#media-2').hide()
```

iFrame player needs to initialise fully before you can hide it.

EDIT:
OK, as it seemed to be a bit buggy, I looked at it again.

This is all I changed ( using main page, not demo script ) and it seems to work ok on IE11 and Chrome. Well it is for me.

```
<DIV class="video-background" id="media-2">
<DIV class="video-foreground">
<DIV id="player2" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class="video-background" id="media-1">
<DIV class="video-foreground">
<DIV id="player1" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
```

Comment: Edit: Only worked for chrome :/   Question still alive.

Comment: @AlphA-Fr . I had another look. EDIT is above to test out.

Comment: All what you changed is the allowfullscreen value set to 0 ? Does not work atm :-)  Only for chrome. Tested on IE and firefox.

Comment: Sorry dude, but I never touched that at all. If you actually take a look at your original code and this, you will see that I have switched players and removed the disply:none completely. It is your code, I only made it work.

Comment: If you are happy, then ok.

Comment: I'm still working on it. I tried to remove and reset all my js code step by step to see what is wrong but it seems firefox kept my videos in his cache.. Could you send me a jsfiddle of what you tested so far ?

Comment: As I needed to see the site fully working, I downloaded it as best as was possible to me. here is a temporary link to what I have. This message and link will be deleted in a few days as will no longer be required ( I hope ), and then we can put the fix on the main answer.   http://www.myonlinelocation.com/AlphA_test/   I only modified what is in my answer above. The rest is as you had it originaly

Comment: Ok, I've the same code as you except for the css part. It should be a css conflict with some -moz -o etc.. values. I will go in the way for tomorrow. Thanks for your time! (tested on dev.alphas-projects/test.php)